# InvalidIndexError when using LIME Tabular Explainer for Regression Task

Tags: lime

I am currently working on a regression task using the `LIME` package in Python. I am trying to use the `LimeTabularExplainer` to help interpret my model's predictions.

Here is how my data is structured:

- `X_train` and `X_test` have dimensions of (752, 15) and (188, 15) respectively,
- `y_train` and `y_test` both have single dimensions of (752,) and (188,) respectively.

I am initializing the `LimeTabularExplainer` as follows:

```
from lime import lime_tabular

explainer = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(
    X_train, 
    mode="regression", 
    feature_names=X_feature_names
)
```

However, when I run this code, I receive the following error:

```
InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), 0)
```

I am not sure why this error is occurring. Any help understanding why I'm receiving this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.